# Why the search time for TreeSet is O(nlogn)?

Tags: algorithms, trees

In my naive opinion it should be O(n) in worst case since Tree could get spindly and unbalanced.

Comment: "Why the search time for TreeSet is O(nlogn)?" - It isn't!!

Comment: You meant O(log n), right?

Comment: @dan04 Yeah I mean logn, typo. I got it now thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[TreeSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) is based on [TreeMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html), which is a [Red-Black Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree) implementation.  Red-Black Trees are [*self-balancing binary search trees*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-balancing_binary_search_tree) that guarantee `O(log n)` performance for search, insert and delete operations.

Comment: It is even guaranteed that the tree stays balanced (whatever operations are made on it), and that balancing guarantee O(log n) performance.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know it's based on a self-balancing tree.